# searchList function Index Out Of Range error

Tags: python, indexing, python-3.4

My program accepts 3 inputs from the user: name, population and county. These details become an array which is then appended to another array. The user then inputs a county name and the corresponding towns details are presented.

I receive an error about about **indexing being out of range** within my function `searchList`.

```
def cathedralTowns():
    def searchList(myCounty, myList): #search function (doesn't work)
        index = 0
        for i in myList:
            myList[index].index(myCounty)
            index += 1
            if myList[index] == myCounty:
                print(myList[index])
    records = [] #main array
    end = False
    while end != True:
        print("\nEnter the details of an English cathedral town.")
        option = input("Type 'Y' to enter details or type 'N' to end: ")
        if option == 'Y':
            name = input("Enter the name of the town: ")
            population = int(input("Enter the population of the town: "))
            county = input("Enter the county the town is in: ")
            records.append([name, population, county]) #smaller array of details of one town
        elif option == 'N':
            print("Input terminated.")
            end = True
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
    print(records) #just for checking what is currently in records array
    end = False
    while end != True:
        print("\nEnter the name of an English county.")
        option = input("Type 'Y' to enter county name or type 'N' to end: ")
        if option == 'Y':
            searchForCounty = input("Enter the name of a county: ")
            searchList(searchForCounty, records) #searchList function takes over from here
        elif option == 'N':
            print("Input terminated.")
            end = True
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please try again.") 

cathedralTowns()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error traceback formatted as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your `searchList` function:

```
def searchList(myCounty, myList):
   for entry in myList:
       if entry[2] == myCounty:
           print("Town: {}, population: {}".format(entry[0], entry[1]))
```

In Python, when you iterate a list, you actually iterate through its elements, thus

```
for entry in myList
```

iterates over each "record" in your list. Then, since you're looking for a county, i.e. the third element in each record you index it with `entry[2]` to compare it to your query, i.e. `myCounty`.

For an example input on a sample records such as:

```
records = [['Canterbury', 45055, 'Kent'], ['Rochester', 27125, 'Kent'], ['Other', 3000, 'Not Kent']]
```

The output for

```
searchList('Kent', records)
```

is:

```
>>> Town: Canterbury, population: 45055
>>> Town: Rochester, population: 27125
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i display the results with just the town name and population in a format like 'town name: population'

Comment: Yes, but i was also wondering how i could format the result so that its a more readeable string representation, without the county displayed

Comment: The updated answer does not display the county... Do you mind providing an expected (i.e. sample) output?

Comment: Yes. Input1 - Canterbury, 45055, Kent    Input2 - Rochester, 27125, Kent

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer to the question